# How to set a height to some buttons of GridLayout in Kivy Python?

Tags: python, button, height, kivy, grid-layout

I'm working in an app with kivy and I have an issue that involve the `GridLayout`. I have a screen with different rows and I want the buttons of the last row to have always the same `height` (11,1% of the height of the Screen). I have tried to modify the attribute height in the buttons but doesn't work properly. With `size_hint_y` works fine , but the fact is that i want to do with `height` because the screen won't have always the same number of rows (is responsive and it depends of the selections of previous screens). I attach here the code that I've done with the attribute height calculated through the command `Window.height/9`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Subject'))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=''))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='1'))
        self.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='2'))
        self.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='3'))
        self.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
        self.add_widget(Label(text='4'))
        self.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
        b1=Button(text='Exit',background_color=[0,1,0,1],height=int(Window.height)/9.0) #doesn't work properly 
        self.add_widget(b1)
        b2=Button(text='Run',background_color=[0,1,0,1],height=int(Window.height)/9.0) #doesn't work properly
        self.add_widget(b2)
        b1.bind(on_press=exit) 




class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__=='__main__':
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

I know it could be done with kivy language in a easier way but for my app is better to do in this way. If anyone knows how to fix this problem I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a widget in a grid/box layout to have a fixed size, you should set its `size_hint` to `None` first. And always use kivy lang at such tasks - no exceptions.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivy.lang import Builder

gui = '''
LoginScreen:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        Label:
            text: 'Subject'

        Label:

        Label:
            text: '1'

        SingleLineTextInput:

        Label:
            text: '2'

        SingleLineTextInput:

        Label:
            text: '3'

        SingleLineTextInput:

        Label:
            text: '4'

        SingleLineTextInput:

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Exit'
            on_press: app.stop()

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Run'


<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False


<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.111
'''


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SimpleKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(gui)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: The fact is that I'm doing in python language and not kivy language because is better for me to develop the app. The gridlayout screen is built with the previous selections of previous screens, that are saved in a list that is iterated to create the final screen. I would like to do with kivy language but I don't know how to read a list of for example 7 elements and create in kivy language 7 rows each with a label and a text input. Finally I've decided to do it with Python language. Your answer has helped me a lot, I would never have thought that setting `size_hint` to `None`  was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cols=2
    self.add_widget(Label(text='Subject'))
    self.add_widget(Label(text=''))
    self.add_widget(Label(text='1'))
    self.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
    self.add_widget(Label(text='2'))
    self.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
    self.add_widget(Label(text='3'))
    self.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
    self.add_widget(Label(text='4'))
    self.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
    b1=Button(text='Exit',background_color=[0,1,0,1],size_hint_y=None, height=int(Window.height)/8.9)  
    self.add_widget(b1)
    b2=Button(text='Run',background_color=[0,1,0,1],size_hint_y=None, height=int(Window.height)/8.9)
    self.add_widget(b2)
    b1.bind(on_press=exit)
```

Edited to change it to be at 11%.

And here one that keeps the button at 11% in response to the window size, where you redraw the Grid Layer whenever the window is resized (as by the bind to 'on_resize').

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):


def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    #init and add grid layer
    self.cols=2
    self.layout = GridLayout(cols=self.cols)
    self.add_widget(self.layout)
    #function to set the buttons based on the current window size
    self.set_content(Window.width, Window.height)
    #bind above function to get called whenever the window resizes
    Window.bind(on_resize=self.set_content)


def set_content(self, width, height, *args):
    #first remove the old sized grid layer
    self.remove_widget(self.layout)
    #now build a new grid layer with the current size
    self.layout =GridLayout(cols=self.cols)
    self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='Subject'))
    self.layout.add_widget(Label(text=''))
    self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='1'))
    self.layout.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
    self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='2'))
    self.layout.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
    self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='3'))
    self.layout.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
    self.layout.add_widget(Label(text='4'))
    self.layout.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False))
    b1=Button(text='Exit',background_color=[0,1,0,1],size_hint_y=None, height=int(Window.height)/8.9)  
    self.layout.add_widget(b1)
    b2=Button(text='Run',background_color=[0,1,0,1],size_hint_y=None, height=int(Window.height)/8.9)
    self.layout.add_widget(b2)
    b1.bind(on_press=exit) 
    #add the newly sized layer
    self.add_widget(self.layout)


class SimpleKivy(App):
def build(self):
    return LoginScreen()


if __name__=='__main__':
SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: I've editted te code because It was wrong. The two attributes were height and I've tried if It worked well and I got the same result. I think I'm doing something in a wrong way.

Comment: I see, so the code above should start you out with the size of the buttons to be at 11% of the window size. If you then want to change that (say half your window is used for something else, and you want to use 11% of half a window), you need to update the button size following that, and that you need to do in a separate function (not the __init__). You could delete your Login Screen and create a new one with the new dimension, but that is not the cleanest. I am working on the same issues myself currently..

Comment: It's easier than this. Only I want the two buttons at the bottom of the screen to be 1/9 of the screen. I don't care about the other fields (`labels` and `textinputs`). I have tried setting a value of pixels (for example '50px') but I got the same result...